# Using OxyPlot to render png images from a PlotModel

Tags: c#, graph, export, png, oxyplot

From the documentation on the [OxyPlot Documentation Website](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/export/export-png.html), it says to use the `PngExporter` class. This class no longer exists in OxyPlot, but rather there are classes called `PngEncoder` and `PngDecoder`. I suspect the equivalent method to `PngExporter.Export` is `PngEncoder.Encode` however it asks for a 2d array of `OxyColor` called "pixels", but I do not know where to get this data from.
**NOTE:** Exporting to SVG or PDF works but this form is useless.

**Problem:** I need to export PNGs from code only of a `PlotModel` in OxyPlot but documentation is outdated.

This is the code I have been told to use:

```
 using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        var pngExporter = new PngExporter();
        pngExporter.Export(plotModel, stream, 600, 400, Brushes.White);
    }
```

Comment: It says in the documentation "The PNG exporters are implemented in the platform specific libraries (OxyPlot.Wpf, OxyPlot.WindowsForms" - have you loaded one of these?

Comment: Using the GitHub version of the project allowed me to get the PngExporter class in OxyPlot.Wpf, ran into a few more problems but eventually it has worked. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [GitHub Oxyplot] files to build the librarys, both oxyplot and oxyplot.wpf , and then use these libraries instead.
Note any method which exports a PNG must be have the STAThread tag.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Jamie's answer, if you want to export a png from say a class library, you can do something like this with STAThread:

```
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            PngExporter.Export(plotModel, @"C:\file.png", 600, 400, OxyColors.White);
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
```

This is using the latest pre-release v1.0.0-unstable2100.